# I'm trying to add fonts in flutter, but I'm getting an error, I couldn't find why

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I'm trying to add fonts in flutter, but I'm getting an error, I couldn't find why

Answer (score 0):

The file path included in `pubspec.yaml` don't match the actual file name in your fonts folder, you added an extra **n** in the path, change :

```
Sevillanna
```

with:

```
Sevillana // removed the extra n in name
```